# SQL alter table works in MySQL but not in Oracle

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle11g

I have created a table `users`

```
create table users (
id int,
name varchar(40)
);
```

Now i want a default value for `name`

This query works in MYSQL but not in Oracle database 11g XE

```
alter table users alter name set default 'user';
```

Can anyone explain why ?

Comment: "*Can anyone explain why*" - because Oracle is different than MySQL: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_3001.htm#SQLRF53201

Comment: Thats a SQL-99 standard query. You mean Oracle dosen't care for the ANSI standards .

Comment: MySQL doesn't care for SQL-99 standards either (actually less than Oracle does)

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for adding a default to an existing column is different in Oracle, viz:

```
alter table users
modify (name default 'user');
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f279c/1)

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct query will be like this:

```
ALTER TABLE users MODIFY name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'user';
```